# Copying formats only from separate Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to copy formatting only from a source sheet that is in a different workbook than the current sheet.  Essentially, the source sheet format changes and I'd like to pull updates to the formatting into my destination sheet (which is the current sheet I would be working in).  I'm using the following code, but I get "Cannot convert Spreadsheet to (class)" error" on the last line.  Any insights?

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Source ID")
var source = ss
var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Destination ID");
var range = source.getRange("N3:AE50");
range.copyFormatToRange(destination, 10, 27, 4, 50);
```

Comment: Your variable `destination` is a [`Spreadsheet`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet), not a [`Sheet`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet). Re-read the documentation carefully: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyFormatToRange(Sheet,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer) In their example, `destination` is another `Sheet`, in the same `Spreadsheet`.

Comment: It was my understanding that "Destination ID" is the specific sheet? Do I append with a .getSheet within my destination var or should a different script be written altogether?

Comment: Read the documentation (and the Apps Script editor's autocomplete pop-up) for methods you are using: `SpreadsheetApp#openById` opens an entirely separate workbook, that has the given spreadsheet id. A spreadsheet id is NOT the same as a "grid id" aka a "sheet id".

Comment: I'm sorry for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the situation what you want? You want to copy the format from Sheet1 to Sheet2. Sheet1 and Sheet2 are in the same Spreadsheet A. Or although Sheet1 is in the Spreadsheet A, Sheet2 is NOT in the Spreadsheet A. Which do you try to do?

Comment: @pnuts Thank you for supporting. I would like to think of the workaround, because ``copyFormatToRange()`` cannot be used for 2 different spreadsheets.

Comment: @pnuts Thank you for the additional information. In the case of the copy of "Conditional formatting" and "format", the Class of SpreadsheetApp usually cannot be used for the 2 different spreadsheet. In this case, I always use Sheets API. By this, the flexibility of copy becomes high. But in this question, I thought that the use of SpreadsheetApp might be suitable in order to reduce an operation load for using script. So I'm thinking of the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You want to copy the format from Spreadsheet A to Spreadsheet B. If my understanding is correct, how about this workaround? I think that there are several answers for your situation, so please think of this as one of them.

As tehhowch pointed out, `copyFormatToRange()` can be used for the same sheets in a Spreadsheet. For this situation, I understood that you want to use for between 2 Spreadsheets. In my workaround, I used the following flow.

1. Copy the source sheet of Spreadsheet with "Source ID" to Spreadsheet with "Destination ID".
2. Retrieve the range from the copied sheet as the source range.
3. Copy the source range to the destination sheet using `copyFormatToRange()`.
4. Delete the copied sheet.

#### Sample script :

```
var sourceA1Notation = "N3:AE50";
var destinationA1Notation = "D10"; // row=4, col=10 This is the cell of upper left for putting the source range.
var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Source ID");
var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Destination ID");

var sourceSheet = source.getSheets()[0]; // You can also use source.getSheetByName(name)
var destinationSheet = destination.getSheets()[0]; // You can also use source.getSheetByName(name)

var copiedsheet = sourceSheet.copyTo(destination);
var sourceRange = copiedsheet.getRange(sourceA1Notation);
var destinationRange = destinationSheet.getRange(destinationA1Notation);
sourceRange.copyFormatToRange(
  destinationSheet,
  destinationRange.getColumn(),
  destinationRange.getColumn() + sourceRange.getNumColumns() - 1,
  destinationRange.getRow(),
  destinationRange.getRow() + sourceRange.getNumRows() - 1
);
destination.deleteSheet(copiedsheet);
```

#### Note :

- When you use this, please input and confirm `sourceA1Notation`, `destinationA1Notation`, `"Source ID"` and `"Destination ID"`.

  - `destinationA1Notation` is the cell of upper left for putting the source range.
- In this sample script, each first sheet of "Source ID" and "Destination ID" is used. If you want to use other sheet, please modify this script.

#### References :

- [copyFormatToRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyformattorangesheet-column-columnend-row-rowend)
- [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets)
- [getSheetByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)

If I misunderstand what you want, I'm sorry.